# Add Rows for months missing from years SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I am working with a table that stores data at a monthly level.  However, for many items, there isn't any entries for some months.  How do I add rows for missing months for specific year range (Example:  2017 - 2020)?

Here's what I have done so far:

--Create temp table to retrieve months and years for the range I am looking to populate rows for:

```
DECLARE @months table (MonthNum int)
DECLARE @i int =1

WHILE (@i<=12)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @months(MonthNum)
SELECT @i
SET @i=@i+1
END

DECLARE @YearsRange TABLE (MonthNum int, YearsRange int)

Insert Into @YearsRange (MonthNum, YearsRange)
(
select *, year(getdate()) as Years from @months
union
select *, year(getdate()) + 1 as Years from @months
union
select *, year(getdate()) + 2 as Years from @months
union
select *, year(getdate()) + 3 as Years from @months
)

select * from @YearsRange
```

Table Structure:

--Rows that are red are the ones I would expect as end result:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Getting a date table is a faq. Please google your title. Please edit your question to be more clear--read & act on [mcve]. What *exactly* is to be the input & output? "add rows for missing months for specific year range" is too vague--someone couldn't leave & come back with a program given that. [Please use text not images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3404097). What does "doing full join between two dates still won't give me the extra rows" mean? (Are the types the same?) Please edit your question with *executable examples* of how you are trying to use the dates table.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use a loop. You can do this with a recursive `CTE` very quickly...

```
declare @start date = '20170101'
declare @end date = '20201201'

;with Rcte as(
    select TheDate = @start
    union all
    select 
        dateadd(month,1,TheDate)
    from 
        Rcte
    where
        TheDate < @end
)

select 
*
from Rcte
full outer join --or using cross apply depending on what you are looking for
yourTable on AsOfDate = TheDate
```

You didn't provide sample data so I didn't break out the date into month and year. But you get the idea here...

Comment: doing full join between two dates still won't give me the extra rows.  Is there a reason why?  Also, the rows you see in red are the expected result.